# Python multiprocessing pool map with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have a function to be called from multiprocessing pool.map with multiple arguments.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def printed(num,num2):
    print 'here now '
    return num

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = Pool(8)

    def callme(self):
        print self.pool.map(printed,(1,2),(3,4))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    aa = A()
    aa.callme()
```

but it gives me following error

```
TypeError: printed() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I have tried solutions from other answers here but they are not working for me.
How can i resolve it and what is the reason for this problem (I did not get the pickle POV)

Comment: marked as duplicate after more than 2 years. However, the question was in context of being used with pickle. The solution was to change definition of printed method `def printed(*args):` as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be giving args in array

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def printed(*args):
    print 'here now '
    return args[0][0]

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = Pool(8)

    def callme(self):
        print self.pool.map(printed,[(1,2),(3,4)])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    aa = A()
    aa.callme()
```

Comment: I solved it by packing the variables earlier. This answer has also worked for my problem